# Working with Excel columns in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have some data (> 1000 rows) in an Excel file like this:

```
Latitude    Longitude   phi
56,4    58,6    68
64,89   -147,79 278
49,69   11,22   77
49,26   119,74  340
34,39   -116,41 306
```

And what I want to do is, getting the average of `phi` values for every 10x10 grid of latitude/longitude.

For example, there are 100 values between LAT 10-20 and LONG 50-60 and I want to make a list the average phi values for that area.

If I do one by one it will look like this but there are too many data;

```
a=[5 15 355];

sins=1/3*((sum(sind(a))));
coses=1/3*((sum(cosd(a))));

result=atand(sins/coses);
result
```

How can I process this data?

After getting the result I want to create another excel including the average phis, something like this

```
    Latitude    Longitude   AV.phi
    10-20       10-20       number*
    10-20       20-30       number*
    10-20       30-40       number*
    10-20       40-50       number*
    10-20       50-60       number*
....
   20-30           10-20    number*
   20-30           20-30    number*
......
```

continues to all lat-long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) to grab the data and then you can perform all of your analysis in MATLAB.

```
% Each column is the same as your excel columns.
data = xlsread(filename);
```

This will return an M x 3 matrix where the columns are your latitude, longitude, and phi and the rows are the rows from your excel sheet.

Then you can use logical indexing to grab the values of interest. So for your example in your question, you would have something like.

```
touse = data(:,1) >= 10 & data(:,1) < 20 & ...   % Latitude in range
        data(:,2) >= 50 & data(:,2) < 60;        % Longitude in range
```

Where `touse` is 1 when the conditions are true and 0 when the conditions are false. Then you can use this logical array to access the `phi` values (column 3) for these latitude/longitudes

```
phis = data(touse,3);
```

Once you have this, you can perform any operation on this array that you want. So based your initial equation, you can do

```
sins = 1 / 3 * sum(sind(phis));
coses = 1 / 3 * sum(cosd(phis));
result = atand(sins / coses);
```

Of if you wanted the mean like you said, you can simply use [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) to get that.

```
meanValue = mean(phis);
```

So now if we want to loop through all latitude/longitude ranges, we can write something like the following to do that.

```
% Step size
dL = 10;
latrange = minLatitude:dL:maxLatitude;
longrange = minLongitude:dL:maxLongitude;

% Figure out what all permutations of lat/long are
[lat, long] = meshgrid(latrange(1:end-1), longrange(1:end-1));

% Pre-allocate the output
result = zeros(size(lat));

% If you also want the means like your question said.
meanValues = zeros(size(lat));

% Now analyze each subgroup individually as we showed above
for k = 1:numel(lat)
    touse = data(:,1) >= lat(k) & data(:,1) < lat(k) + dL & ...
            data(:,2) >= long(k) & data(:,2) < long(k) + dL

    phis = data(touse,3);

    % Compute the mean
    meanValues(k) = mean(phis);

    % Compute your other value that you used as an example
    sins = 1 / 3 * sum(sind(phis)); 
    coses = 1 / 3 * sum(cosd(phis));
    result(k) = atand(sins / coses);

    if coses < 0
        result(k) = result(k) + 180;
    elseif sins < 0 && coses > 0
        result(k) = result(k) + 360;
    end
end
```

Where `result` will contain your value for each range of latitude and longitude.

**Edit**

To write this data back out to a file as you've requested, you can do the following.

```
output = cell(numel(result) + 1, 3);

% Add the headers
output(1,:) = {'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Avg Phi'};

% Helper function for printing ranges as strings
printRange = @(x)sprintf('%d-%d', x, x + dL);

% Latitude/Longitude columns
output(2:end,1) = arrayfun(printRange, lat(:), 'uni', 0);
output(2:end,2) = arrayfun(printRange, long(:), 'uni', 0);

% Mean Value of Phi for 3rd column
output(2:end,3) = num2cell(result(:));

% Now write out to excel
xlswrite(outputfilename, output);
```

Comment: How can I make this results in order ? Like my first excel file LAT LONG and Average Phi .

Comment: @Berk The second part of this answer should do it all in order. The output should be M x N where the rows are the different latitude bins and the columns are the different longitude bins. They are already in numeric order.

Comment: yes I get the resuts by matrix form by this method thanks, but is there any way to make it column row style like above ? I'm trying to graph it and I need A-B-C columns LAT-LONG-Average phi respectively.

Comment: @Berk so you want all values of `phi` in the input replaced with the average values?

Comment: yes , its true like that will be good but not all the lat-long wil be listed. only the results like 10 10 55, 10 30 68.

Comment: @Berk It's not clear what you want. Can you add example of the expected output to your original question?

Comment: I edit end of my question above, after I getting the results I need in that shape.

Comment: @Berk OK great. Answer is updated to give you the output you're expecting.

Comment: I get an error Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in kod (line 46)
output(2:end,1) = arrayfun(printRange, lat, 'uni', 0);  and I want to put "result" to the third column (the one with atand(sins / coses), not the "meanValues" code if its possible

Comment: @Berk Updated to pass the correct values. Hopefully it works now! There was a small typo on the line `output = cell(numel(result) + 1, 3)`

Comment: both size(lat) and size(long) gives;   6  6  .  for now min max lat long is 20 to 80

Comment: @Berk check it out now and see how that goes.

Comment: Still error on Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. output(2:end,1) = arrayfun(printRange, lat, 'uni', 0);

Comment: @Berk Oh right. They're 2D. Gotta flatten them with `(:)`. Changed a few lines to account for this.

Comment: I want to add 3 if commands to my code on the formula. IF  "sins>0" and "coses>0" then result = atand(sins / coses); as usual, IF coses<0 then "result+180", IF "sins<0 and coses>0" then result+360". How can it be done ?

Comment: @Berk Answer has been updated to take this into account.